# Is it possible to do orderBy() or orderBy() in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

Is it possible to do `orderBy()` `or` `orderBy()` in Laravel Eloquent?  My current query only sorts the `item.ItemID` upon user clicking sort on the frontend but it won't sort `item.Desc` when the user clicks sort on the frontend.

I've tried putting these `orderBy()`s inside of a `where()` clause using a closure but that didn't work either.  Does anyone know of a good way I could rectify this?

```php
$this->model
    ->join('awards', 'item.ItemID', '=', 'awards.LinkID')
    ->join('opportunities', 'awards.AwardID', '=', 'branch.AwardID')
    ->groupBy('item.ItemID', 'item.Desc')
    ->orderBy('item.ItemID', $clickedDInventoryItemIdFlag ? 'DESC' : 'ASC')
    ->orderBy('item.Desc', $clickedDescriptionColumnFlag ? 'DESC' : 'ASC')
    ->select("item.ItemID", "item.Desc", "branch.OppID")
    ->get();
```

Comment: i dont understand what you mean by `orderBy() "OR" orderBy()`, what is resolving this 'OR'?

Comment: @lagbox What I mean is - is it possible to separate the sorting so that the user has a choice to sort one at a time upon clicking

Comment: so you want a conditional to decide which orderBy to use?

Comment: @lagbox yeah that's what I meant, sorry about that.

Comment: you can do that with `if` statements or using the `when` method of the builder to check a value and act accordingly

Comment: This is a frontend matter not a backend one. You can use JavaScript to make your data sort responsive.

Answer (score 1):

Ordering in SQL is cumulative, so you'll always be ordering by the first item, then the second. Instead you can [manipulate the query based on a condition](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses):

```php
$this->model
    ->join('awards', 'item.ItemID', '=', 'awards.LinkID')
    ->join('opportunities', 'awards.AwardID', '=', 'branch.AwardID')
    ->groupBy('item.ItemID', 'item.Desc')
    ->when(
        $clickedDescriptionColumnFlag,         // condition
        fn ($q) => $q->orderBy('item.Desc')    // true
        fn ($q) => $q->orderBy('item.ItemID')  // false
    )
    ->select("item.ItemID", "item.Desc", "branch.OppID")
    ->get();
```

I have to say though, whenever I see query builder joins happening like this, it's a big flag telling me that you likely don't understand [model relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships). (And the fact that you used "Eloquent" in your title, despite there being no such code in the question!) I would strongly suggest looking into how [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent) works; for all but the heaviest loads the increase in coding efficiency far outweighs the slight decrease in database query efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Until you call `get()` method it is all query builder since all chaining methods return `self` instance. So you can separate chain and use if block when needed:

```
$someModels = $this->SomeModel
    ->join('awards', 'item.ItemID', '=', 'awards.LinkID')
    ->join('opportunities', 'awards.AwardID', '=', 'branch.AwardID')
    ->groupBy('item.ItemID', 'item.Desc');

if ($condition) {
    $someModels->orderBy('item.ItemID', $clickedDInventoryItemIdFlag ? 'DESC' : 'ASC')
} else {
    $someModels->orderBy('item.Desc', $clickedDescriptionColumnFlag ? 'DESC' : 'ASC');
}

$someModels
    ->select("item.ItemID", "item.Desc", "branch.OppID")
    ->get();
```